# Order posts inside bootstrap card columns

Tags: posts, wp-query, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 4 card columns masonry like grid. I want to show six posts form my articles and I'm using a custom query to retrieve the posts. All works fine, but the posts aren't showed with the order I want. I don't know if it's because the card columns bootstrap settings or because the wordpress query. Is there a simple way to order the loaded posts with a custom order?

here is the example of my wp query

```php
<?php
$clients = ['199','168','86','291','113','229'];

$portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'status'        => 'published',
  'category_name' => 'Portfolio',
    'posts_per_page'=> 6,
    'post__in' => $clients
));
?>

<div class="card-columns">
<?php if( $portfolio->have_posts() ): while( $portfolio->have_posts() ): $portfolio->the_post();  ?>
    <div class="card hide">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
          <img class="card-img-top w-100" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>" id="case-studies">
          <div class="overlay"><h4 class="text-center" id="client-name"><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div>
      </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the `order` and `orderby` parameters of `WP_Query`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Comment: "I don't know if it's because the card columns bootstrap settings or because the wordpress query"  figure that out and then you will know which path to investigate on sorting

Comment: @MikeNGarrett Solved by using the `orderby` param in `WP_Query()` Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`order`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and [`orderby`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) parameters of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).